# Не работает задача hangfire

Tags: c#, .net-core, hangfire

Всем привет. Недавно мне пришлось использовать hangfire для запуска определённой задачи.

При запуске задачи я получаю вот такое исключение в самом планировщике:

```
Failed
An exception occurred during processing of a background job.

System.InvalidOperationException
A suitable constructor for type 'SMSServicePanel.GetInfoForResourseService' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'SMSServicePanel.GetInfoForResourseService' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Hangfire.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
   at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)
```

Вот код всей задачи:

```
public class jsonserialize
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string count { get; set; }
}
public class GetInfoForResourseService
{
    public EFUserDBContext db;
    public IInfoWithPanelRepository infoWithPanelRepository;
    GetInfoForResourseService(EFUserDBContext db, IInfoWithPanelRepository infoWithPanelRepository)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.infoWithPanelRepository = infoWithPanelRepository;
    }
    private async Task<String> Request()
    {
        var appSettingsJson = AppSettingsJson.GetAppSettings();
        var ip = appSettingsJson["SMSServiceIP"];
        var apikey = appSettingsJson["ApiKeySMSService"];
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create($"http://{ip}/stubs/monitors_ajax.php");
        request.Method = "POST"; // для отправки используется метод Post
                                 // данные для отправки
        string data = $"api_key={apikey}";
        // преобразуем данные в массив байтов
        byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        // устанавливаем тип содержимого - параметр ContentType
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Устанавливаем заголовок Content-Length запроса - свойство ContentLength
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        //записываем данные в поток запроса
        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        return result;
    }
    public async Task GetInfo()
    {
        var jsonstring = await Request();
        Root result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonstring);
        var resourselist = new List<jsonserialize>();
        foreach (var item in result.unprocessed_requests)
        {
            var addedItem = new jsonserialize() { name = item.server_name, count = item.requests_count };
            resourselist.Add(addedItem);
        }
        var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(resourselist);
        InfoWithPanel info = await db.Infos.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            var addedinfo = new InfoWithPanel() { Resourses = json, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now };
            infoWithPanelRepository.Create(addedinfo);
        }
        else
        {
            var updatedinfo = new InfoWithPanel() { id = info.id, Resourses = json, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now };
            infoWithPanelRepository.Update(updatedinfo);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

}

В чём может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В ошибке вам что говорят? Нет подходящего публичного конструктора, либо в нем типы не зарегистрированы. Где у вас допустим публичный конструктор у класса `GetInfoForResourseService`?

Comment: Напишите конструктору `public`.

Comment: `WebRequest` устарел, используйте `HttpClient`, к тому же он значительно быстрее работает (если правильно его использовать, см. документацию).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо ребятам из комментариев. Я присвоил конструктору модификатор доступности public и теперь всё заработало.